# Filter data inside array object of array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to filter data inside array object of array object, Please find below code for more information.

```js
var data = [
  {
    name:'testdata1',
    subdata:[{status:'fail'},{status:'success'}] 
  },
  {
    name:'testdata2',
    subdata:[{status:'fail'},{status:'success'}] 
  }
]
```

Expected Data:

```js
var successdata = [
  {
    name:'testdata1',
    subdata:[status:'success'}]
  },
  {
    name:'testdata2',
    subdata:[status:'success'}] 
  }
];

var FailureData =[
  {
    name:'testdata1',
    subdata:[{status:'fail'}]
  },
  {
    name:'testdata2',
    subdata:[{status:'fail'}] 
  }
];
```

I missed curly braces,So i am updating

Comment: You can't do that. Repetitive properties will replace the ones before.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate property name for same object. Like "status" property in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'testdata1', subdata: [{status: 'fail'}, {
        status:
            'success'
    }]
},
    {
        name: 'testdata2', subdata:
            [{status: 'success'}, {status: 'fail'}]
    }
];

const filterData = (data, status) => data.reduce((acc, val) => {

    const sub = val.subdata.map((v) => v.status === status ? ({ name: val.name, subdata: [v] }) : null).filter(f => f !== null);

    return acc.concat(sub);
}, []);

const successData = filterData(data, 'success');
const failureData = filterData(data, 'fail');

console.log('successData', successData);
console.log('failureData', failureData);
```

Comment: Hi @Alex: My requirement is almost same as this question. And i tried with your answer, too but am not getting the exact output. Can you please help me?
https://jsfiddle.net/jasie/4jhd7zrs/10/

Comment: Hi @aananddham. Not very clear what you mean. You mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zx9bjn4u/4/

Comment: Hi @Alex, i got the result by doing this way as you suggested above: https://jsfiddle.net/jasie/4jhd7zrs/12/

Answer (score 1):

You could map your arrays using Array.map():

```
var successData = data.map(item => ({name: item.name, subdata:[{status:'success'}]})
```

Comment: Please try with foloowing data    var data = [{name:'testdata1',subdata:[{status:'fail'},status:'success'}] },{name:'testdata2',subdata:[{status:'success'},{status:'fail'}] }]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{name:'testdata1',subdata:[{status:'fail'}, {status:'success'}] },{name:'testdata2',subdata:[{status:'success'}, {status:'fail'}] }]


var successData = filterByStatus('success', data);
var failureData = filterByStatus('fail', data);

function filterByStatus(status, data) {
  return data.map(d => {
   var newObj = Object.assign({}, d);
   newObj.subdata = newObj.subdata.filter(s => s.status === status);
   return newObj;
  });
}

console.log('successData', successData);
console.log('failureData', failureData);
```

one of possible ways to do what you want if you have one success property in your object

Comment: Please try with foloowing data    var data = [{name:'testdata1',subdata:[{status:'fail'},status:'success'}] },{name:'testdata2',subdata:[{status:'success'},{status:'fail'}] }]

Comment: I have updated my answer with new data, please check

Answer (score 1):

What I guess you want to do is filter the array based on subdata status. 
I also guess that what subdata should have is just the status property and your code would be: var data = [{name:'testdata1',subdata:[{status:'fail'},{status:'success'}] }.

Then you want to look in the subdata array and find which data have success and failure in them.

So what you could be looking for is this:

```
var successData = data.filter(sdata => { 
   var successFlag=false;
   sdata.subdata.forEach(subdata=>{
       if (subdata.status==='success'){
            successFlag = true;
       }
   }
   return successFlag;
}
```

The same with the failureData.

For more information you could check the Array.prototype.filter function: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

P.S. As mentioned in a comment to your question as well, your subdata array cannot be an object with two of the same property

Comment: Please try with foloowing data    var data = [{name:'testdata1',subdata:[{status:'fail'},status:'success'}] },{name:'testdata2',subdata:[{status:'success'},{status:'fail'}] }]